# How to format a div id in a div class?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="content">
    <div class ="imgs">
      <a href="#"><img src="images" alt="some_text" width="250" height="210"></a>
</div>
<div class = "compu">
    <div id="titulo">text</br></div>
    <div id="subtitle">text </div>              
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I format the text in **titulo** and **subtitle**??

The css that i have for **compu**:

```
.compu
{
    position: relative; 
    width: 250px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    color: #1B57A0;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    line-height:120%;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

I don't know much about html and css, and this is my first project, thank you

Comment: Could you expand on `format the text`?

Comment: what is that <tr> doing there??\

Comment: @Hashem I guess he want different stlye for each text.

Comment: css class with `.compu div{ }` may work

Comment: If `.compu` is not working, make sure each `#titulo`/`#subtitle` element don't have any special style.

Comment: You will need to provide a fallback for your font family - not may windows computers have helvetica installed so you may want to do something like this: `font-family: Helvetica,  sans-serif, Arial;`

Comment: Just use `#titulo` and `#subtitle`. No need to be overly specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can give css to style titulo and subtitle like as follow

```
    .compu #titulo
    {
         /*write your style code here*/
    }

    .compu #subtitle
    {
         /*write your style code here*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select the div with the class `compu` and than the lower divs with a `id`. Like this

**Css:**

```
.compu #titulo { /* Style of the titulo div */ }
.compu #subtitle { /* Style of the subtitle div */  }
```

Here you can style both div's.

Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VTsXW/)**

The css used in the demo:

```
.compu #titulo { color:red; font-size:20px;}
.compu #subtitle { color:green; font-size:14px;}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
.compu #titulo
{
}
.compu #subtitle
{

}
```